# Delete a record from Access database based on name

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Database Access 2007 with VB.net:

I've DB name: Sample

Table name: test

Columns:

```
empname[Primary Key], 
id,
sal
```

I want to delete the record based on name. for eg: my name col contains names like james,rocky,gates etc.
What I want to do is, if I press delete button I should get pop-up message box asking to enter employee name, after entering if the emp name exists then it should delete it and update the access database and if the emp name not found it should say "No record exists with this name".

2nd question is: I am displaying records in DataGridview, I want to modify the particular record from datagridview that should inturn updates the access database.

I would be great help for me, if I get this working.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to break the problem down into the various parts and see if you can solve them, then post the code and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Create a query in Access or use a sql string like 'Delete From test Where empname = @p1'.

Show the user a form (or use InputBox) to get the name.

Put the name you've obtained from your form/InputBox into your query/sql string.

Run the query.

If your DataGridView is bound to your table, surely you get all of this for free?